# Increase performance in database synchronizations using Sync Framework

Tags: synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

Right now I'm using SyncFramework 2.1 to synchronize two database (almost 3GB of data) and the process is the way to slow.
Sometimes I get an exception indicating "Timeout or remote database doesn´t respond".
I figured out recently that during SelectionChanges activity the changes are stored in memory and the application starts to consume lots of memory, sometimes I get the exception:

`The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info: System.OutOfMemoryException`

So, does anyone know what I'm doing wrong ? The memory issue is normal in Sync Framework ?

Any help will be appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what databases platforms are you synching and which sync provider are you using.

if you're using the SqlCeSyncProvider/SqlSyncProvider, you can set memory-based batching and likewise, you can also set the SQL command timeouts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm using Sql Server at remote database and Sql Express Local Db on the clients databases. My provider is SqlSyncProvider

Comment: I tried set the memory-based batching and it work fine for now! Thanks JuneT